# YouTube onStateChange event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, youtube

I was wondering why YouTube onPlayerStateChange is not working properly.

In that scenario I don't get any alert message (or any other event) when the youtube video ended.

Any Idea ?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<body>

<iframe src=""></iframe>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>    
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            alert('VIDEO IS ENDED'); // <<<--- THIS IS NOT WORKING
            break;
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var vidId = 'uIv6u7pdR5I';
    $('iframe').attr('src', "https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/" + vidId);
        new YT.Player('player_'+vidId, {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            },
            playerVars: { autohide: 1, showinfo: 0 }
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine if you use the Youtube api as in the instructions at https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Ie, something like this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<body>

<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
            alert('VIDEO IS ENDED'); // <<<--- THIS IS WORKING
            break;
    }
}

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    var vidId = 'uIv6u7pdR5I';
       player= new YT.Player('player', {
            videoId: vidId,
            events: {
//                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            },
            playerVars: { autohide: 1, showinfo: 0 }
        });
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

With your code I got errors because you did not wait for the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady callback and onReady referenced a function that did not exist.
Also, your setting the iframe src to a youtube video url did of course cause a video to show on the page but that had no relation to the Youtube api so there was no reason why onPlayerStateChange would trigger by that player.